# Multiple ProxyPassReverse for a Virtual Host with identical URLs

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

We have a situation where we have one JBoss application that is being proxied by two Apache paths as a Virtual Host below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost1
   ProxyPass /abba/ http://localhost:8080/app/
   ProxyPass /babba/ http://localhost:8080/app/
   ProxyPassReverse /abba/ http://localhost:8080/app/
   ProxyPassReverse /babba/ http://localhost:8080/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

The routing of /abba/ and /babba/ need to go to the same application - going forward we are using rewrites to add some parameters that the application uses to configure itself based on whether /abba/ or /babba/.

However when the application sends a redirect the ProxyPassReverse does not work as access sayfrom /babba/ gets redirected to /abba/.

I understand the reason as it's the same application - however is there are way of configuring Apache to support two difference routes (ProxyPass and ReverseProxyPass) to the same application.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried duplicating the VirtualHost and changing the duplicate to server name "localhost2"?